# Azure Function App Authentication Sign In

Tags: authentication, azure-functions

I am currently working on a function app and would like to understand more on the built in authentication using Microsoft as the identity provider.  I have created an app registration as per this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#configure-client-apps-to-access-your-app-service) but upon testing the authentication in a browser, I have been redirected to login.microsoftonline.com/common instead of login.microsoftonline.com/.  Is that the expected behavior?

[image]

Comment: If you have registered your app as Web, you can provide a redirect URL. If you had registered your app as Mobile or desktop app, then default redirect URL will be going to "/common". Read the answers from Azure team in this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/25418/how-to-add-aad-authentication-azure-function.html), and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url) provides more clarity.

Comment: I have already provided a redirect URL which is pointed to <function app url>/.auth/login/aad/callback.  My question for the redirect was more from the sign-in endpoint.

Comment: For your function app, in the Authentication blade, check what is being displayed for ```Issuer Url``` for the Microsoft authentication provider. If you have configured to authenticate users from your organization's Azure AD, then that will be the tenant ID, and the url would look like https://login.microsoftonline.com/<guid of tenant>. It depends on what you chose for your target audience, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps#who-can-sign-in-to-your-app)

Comment: The issuer url initially was blank.  I added login.microsoftonline.com/<guid of tenant>, and it now redirects as I would like.  Looks like it really needs the Issuer URL to be provided.  Thanks for the help Anand!

Comment: thanks for confirming @carterjordan, I have posted it as answer, please mark it as accepted so that it helps others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your function app, in the Authentication blade, check what is being displayed for `Issuer Url` for the Microsoft Authentication provider. If you have configured to authenticate users from your organization's Azure AD, then that will be the tenant ID, and the url should be `login.microsoftonline.com/<guid of tenant>`. It depends on what you chose for your target audience, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps#who-can-sign-in-to-your-app).